# Unable to parse WSDLs into different packages with jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have configured my jaxb2-maven-plugin to pick up the WSDLs from different folders under same location and parse them into different packages as the functionality they deliver is different. On running mvn install, only the first wsdl is processed and the 2nd one gets ignored. Upon changing the version from 1.5 to 1.6, only the 2nd WSDL gets processed and the first one is ignored, which looks a bit strange. I would expect both of them to be processed and packaged properly, please suggest any changes that are needed in the syntax/plugin.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>xjc-rules</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaFiles>*.wsdl</schemaFiles>
            <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
            <wsdl>true</wsdl>
            <args>-wsdl</args>
            <packageName>com.baplc.ngs.dealing.rules</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>xjc-infra</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/infracloud</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaFiles>*.wsdl</schemaFiles>
            <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
            <wsdl>true</wsdl>
            <args>-wsdl</args>
            <packageName>com.baplc.ngs.dealing.informatica.cloud</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the following line inside the `configuration` of all `execution`s:

```
<clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
```

(Technically, you only need to include it in the second execution, but I like to have the configs similar.)

The parameter `clearOutputDir` is set to true by default and will delete the content of the outputDirectory (defaults to `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb`).

When `clearOutputDir` is set to true, the first WSDL file is processed in the first execution. In the second execution, the output directory is cleared (thus the generated files from first execution are removed) and the second file is processed. So you see only the generated classes from the second file.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#clearOutputDir).